# ReactJS: Nested loop rendering element in 2D without relying on array or object

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, jsx

I am trying to render out a 10 x 10 checkbox input form in JSX by relying on the setState() changes, as I intended to have user to be able to change the number of dimension to render the likes of 20x20 or 15x15. I have tried map(items => {}) and it is not working.

```
const [xCells, setXCells] = useState(10)
const [yCells, setYCells] = useState(10)
let arrX = Array.apply(null, { length: xCells }).map(Number.call, Number)
let arrY = Array.apply(null, { length: yCells }).map(Number.call, Number)
return (
  <div className="RestaurantSeating">
    {' '}
    {arrX.map(item => {
      arr.map(item => {
        return <input type="checkbox" />
      })
    })}{' '}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried even if it's not working atm

Comment: `const [ xCells, setXCells ] = useState(10);
    const [ yCells, setYCells ] = useState(10);

    let arrX = Array.apply(null, {length: xCells}).map(Number.call, Number);
    let arrY = Array.apply(null, {length: yCells}).map(Number.call, Number);

    return (
        <div className="RestaurantSeating">
            {
                arrX.map(item => {
                    arr.map(item => {
                        return <input type="checkbox"/>
                    })
                })
            }
        </div>
    );`

Comment: Change this:
`arrX.map(item => {
      arr.map(item => {`
to this:
`arrX.map(item => {
      return arrY.map(item =>{`

Also, always add a unique key for each element in the array. E.g. `<element key={some_key} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're using curly braces in your map functions `{}` which mean you should explicitly write the return i.e. `return arrY.map...`, currently you are returning nothing (`undefined`). Or you can omit the braces to implicitly return the yCells map:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [xCells, setXCells] = React.useState(10)
  const [yCells, setYCells] = React.useState(10)

  let arrX = Array.apply(null, { length: xCells }).map(Number.call, Number)
  let arrY = Array.apply(null, { length: yCells }).map(Number.call, Number)

  return (
    <div className="RestaurantSeating">
      {arrX.map(x => 
        <div key={x} className="row">
          {arrY.map(y =>
            <input key={y} type="checkbox" />
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It kind of worked but not as I expected. I'm intended to have it 10 x 10, which will have the size of  X * Y that will align horizontally and vertically

Comment: @MEMYSELF see my edited answer - you can put each 10 items in a div to align it

Comment: Ok, that is what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for this will be:

```
{new Array(xCells).fill(0).map(_ => {
    return (<div>
        {new Array(yCells).fill(0).map(_ => {
            return <input type="checkbox" />
        })}
    </div>)
})}
```

```js
function Test(){
  const [xCells, setXCells] = React.useState(10);
  const [yCells, setYCells] = React.useState(10);
  return (
    <div className="RestaurantSeating">
      {' '}
      {new Array(xCells).fill(0).map(_ => {
        return (<div>
          {new Array(yCells).fill(0).map(_ => {
            return <input type="checkbox" />
          })}
        </div>)
      })}{' '}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve. Fantastic, thanks!!